# Adding role to user, getting a SQL timeout

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, integration-testing, owin, localdb

In my application (MVC/WebAPI, using Owin) I've setup integration testing using a localDB. In one of my tests I seem to be able to query data from the UserManager, but I can't update any data.

**ApplicationUserManager setup:**

```
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> store) : base(store)
    {
        UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(this)
        {
            AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
            RequireUniqueEmail = true
        };

        PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
        {
            RequiredLength = 6,
            RequireNonLetterOrDigit = true,
            RequireDigit = true,
            RequireLowercase = true,
            RequireUppercase = true,
        };

        UserLockoutEnabledByDefault = true;
        DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
        MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout = 5;
    }
}
```

**Unity Setup:**

```
container
    .RegisterType<DbContext, ApplicationDbContext>()
    .RegisterType<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>, UserStore<ApplicationUser>>()
    .RegisterType<IAuthenticationManager>(new InjectionFactory(o => HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication))
    .RegisterType<IRoleStore<IdentityRole, string>, RoleStore<IdentityRole, string, IdentityUserRole>>()
    .RegisterType<ApplicationUserManager>()
    .RegisterType<ApplicationSignInManager>()
    .RegisterType<ApplicationRoleManager>()
```

**Code being tested:**

```
//Working
var user = await _applicationUserManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
//SQL timeout
identityResult = await _applicationUserManager.AddToRoleAsync(user.Id, Roles.User);
```

I've tried other updates (like updating the username), but none of it seems to be working. When I call the same functionality while using the website (or in an API call using Postman) everything is working just fine.

Any suggestions?

**Update 1:**

When I raise my sql timeout setting to 180 seconds, I'm able to get past the first usermanager update (after waiting about 60 seconds). Any following call to the database fails with a provider failed on open.

**Update 2:**

I've tested localdb performance in the same method:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    _test.LogError(new System.Exception(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
}
```

This operation (1000 inserts with varying data) takes about 1 second to complete.

**Update 3:**

When I pause the test after updating the user, I can't reach the database in SSMS anymore. It seems to be in a locked state.

**Update 4:**

For testing purposes I've written the update code in the usermanager myself. I'm not getting a timeout anymore, but the it seems to keep a connection or transaction open. While running the following code I can't seem to select anything from the user table in SSMS anymore.

```
var userToUpgrade = _context.Users.Single(user => user.Id == userId);

foreach (var role in userToUpgrade.Roles.ToList())
{
    userToUpgrade.Roles.Remove(role);
}

userToUpgrade.Roles.Add(new IdentityUserRole
{
    UserId = userId,
    RoleId = _context.Roles.Single(role => role.Name == Roles.TestUser).Id
});

_context.Entry(userToUpgrade).State = EntityState.Modified;
_context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Any update/insert/delete triggers on the table?

Comment: No triggers on the table. When I pause the test and update the data manually in ssms everything is working fine.

Comment: Does your code use any transactions?

Comment: No, in the scope of this call it doesn't use any transactions. It feels like there is a transaction hanging in IdentityDbContext, but it isn't created by me.

Comment: Trigger the timeout condition, and look at your database, see if you have a deadlock and what's causing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well that was stupid.

Changed the following code:

```
internal void StartTestScope()
{
    _transactionScope = new TransactionScope();
}
```

To:

```
internal void StartTestScope()
{
    TransactionOptions options = new TransactionOptions();
    options.IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted;
    _transactionScope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew, options);
}
```

Before starting my integration test, I start a new scope/transaction. After running the test, I tear it down. The usermanager internally started its own transaction, resulting in me not being able to read the changes.

Thanks for the suggestions, helped me in the right direction!